# How to check if two containers are linked properly?

Tags: docker

I have 3 containers, say their names are `A`, `B`, `C`.

Their definition, now that I tried to link them together (using the key `links`), is attached at the end of the question.

How can I test that this linking worked properly?

```
 {
            'A': {
                'run_args': {
                    'name': 'A',
                    'detach': 'True',
                    'volumes': {
                        '/var/run/datadog': {'bind': '/var/run/datadog', 'mode': 'rw'}
                    },
                    'ports': {'30000/tcp': '30000', '30010/tcp': '30010'},
                    'restart_policy': {'name': 'always'},
                    'log_config': {'type': 'syslog'},
                    'command': A_cmd,
                    'links': {'B': 'B', 'C': 'C'}
                }
            },
            'B': {
                'run_args': {
                    'name': 'B',
                    'detach': True,
                    'volumes': {
                        '/etc/salt': {'bind': '/etc/salt', 'mode': 'rw'},
                        '/var/run/datadog': {'bind': '/var/run/datadog', 'mode': 'rw'}
                    },
                    'ports': {'8080/tcp': '80'},
                    'restart_policy': {'name': 'always'},
                    'command': B_cmd,
                    'tty': True,
                    'links': {'A': 'A', 'C': 'C'}
                }
            },
            'C': {
                'run_args': {
                    'name': 'C',
                    'detach': True,
                    'volumes': {
                        '/etc/salt': {'bind': '/etc/salt', 'mode': 'rw'},
                        '/var/run/datadog': {'bind': '/var/run/datadog', 'mode': 'rw'}
                    },
                    'ports': {'33000/tcp': '33000'},
                    'restart_policy': {'name': 'always'},
                    'command': C_cmd,
                    'tty': True,
                    'links': {'A': 'A', 'B': 'B'}
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is this file? Is it snippet from docker-compose file? Please add proper details to the question.

Comment: You shouldn't need `links` at all in modern Docker.

Answer (score 1):

ping container names from another container. If they are linked then it will respond.

Comment: Ok, I will trythis after the weekend and see if it works. thanks.